# why sleep will disable the mutex in go?

Tags: go, mutex, sleep

This is a buyTicket program, and when ticket is 0, it will display "sell out". I wonder know why I can not add sleep in buyTicket Function and why ticket will be negative?

```
 func(t *Ticket) buyTicket() {
        if t.getSpareTicket() <= 0 {
            log.Print("sell out")
            return
        }
        t.mu.Lock()
        t.numTicket--
        time.Sleep(time.Microsecond)
        log.Printf("there are %d", t.numTicket)
        t.mu.Unlock()
    }
    
    func (t *Ticket) getSpareTicket() int{
        t.mu.Lock()
        defer t.mu.Unlock()
        return t.numTicket
    }
    
    
    func main() {
        buyer := &Ticket{}
        buyer.mu = sync.Mutex{}
        buyer.numTicket = 100
        for buyer.getSpareTicket() > 0 {
            //time.Sleep(time.Microsecond)
            go func() {
                log.Printf("number buy a ticket")
                buyer.buyTicket()
            }()
        }
    
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
        //l := buyer.getSpareTicket()
        //fmt.Println(l)
    }
```

when I add time.sleep(time.microsecond) in function buyTicket, the ticket will be negative, I want to know why this happen?

This is the result:

```
2020/11/15 15:36:00 there are 2
2020/11/15 15:36:00 there are 1
2020/11/15 15:36:00 there are 0
2020/11/15 15:36:00 there are -1
2020/11/15 15:36:00 there are -2
2020/11/15 15:36:00 there are -3
2020/11/15 15:36:00 there are -4
2020/11/15 15:36:00 there are -5
```

Comment: This happens because the for condition is checked well before the goroutines start running.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several problems with the program:

1- The for loop creates goroutines *while* the number of spare tickets is nonzero. This will create many goroutines as they will not immediately execute and reduce ticket numbers

2- In buyTicket, you check, and then buy. Another goroutine can go in do the same after one goroutine checks, decides to continue and buys a ticket.

The solution is to fix buyTicket to lock on entry unlock on exit, and check for the ticket count without calling getSpareTicket, because getSpareTicket also locks the same mutex, which will cause a deadlock.

Comment: Thank you for answer. There are no problem when I delete sleep in buyTicket, I wonder know why add sleep may cause ticket can become negative. Also, I tried your solution, it will get deadlock.

Comment: It will not deadlock if you lock once when you enter buyTicket, unlock on return, and not call getSpareTicket in buyTicket.

Comment: With sleep, the time mutex stays locked is longer, making it more likely to have several goroutines call getSpareTicket(), seeing the result larger than zero and proceeding to buy the ticket. Then they all wait to enter into critical section, causing negative ticket count. Your program has a race without the sleep. If you run it sufficiently many times, it will fail eventually.